# Hadoop task tracker - all local directories are not writable

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have a 10 node cluster. 
When I submit Hive jobs I get the below error -

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task Tracker local Incorrect permission for /data/gomz/mapred/local, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while actual: rwxrwxr-x
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start TaskTracker because org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: all local directories are not writable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.checkLocalDirs(TaskTracker.java:5268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeDirectories(TaskTracker.java:907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:2176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:5310)
```

`mapred.local.dir` in both `mapred-site.xml` and `taskcontroller.cfg` point to `/data/gomz/mapred/local`

For my Hive sessions, I use the following settings:

```
SET hive.exec.scratchdir=/dev/tmp/hive;
SET hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/dev/warehouse; (setting works for Hive jobs that do not launch MR)
```

What other local directories could the error be referring to ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check permission of `/data`?

Can you try this command?

```
sudo chown $USER /data
```

After executing this command, try again.

Comment: sudo chown $USER /data  

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for usernick:
usernick is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Do one thing change the dir name /data into /home/$USER/data

Comment: Permission for /data , /data/gomz are set as 755 , whereas for /data/gomz/mapred it is set as 775
Do you reckon that this might be a reason (it appears as a WARNING in the logs I have pasted above though)?


ls -l /data/
total 24
drwx------.  2 root root 16384 Dec  5 11:32 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 gomz gomz  4096 May  8 12:50 gomz
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root root  4096 Dec  5 15:14 postfix

ls -l /data/gomz
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 gomz gomz 4096 May  8 12:50 mapred

ls -l /data/gomz/mapred
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 6 gomz gomz 4096 May  8 13:00 local

Comment: It need permission of /data dir then only it will run.

Comment: First do sudo chown $USER /data

Comment: then only it will run.